# three dimensional vectors in C++

Tags: c++

I have in my c++ code:

```
  typedef vector<int> cards;
  typedef vector<cards> rows;
  typedef vector<rows> matriz;
```

and in my `int main()` , i try to initilizate a matriz called "cartas" with this line;

```
  63  cin>>n>>m;
  66  cartas(n,rows(m, cards(0)));
```

but, with g++, get out this error:

```
flip.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
flip.cpp:66: error: no match for call to ‘(matriz) (int&, rows)’
```

i want to take a matriz of `n*m`, where in each position, there is vector of integers.

thanks, now, i don't see it how.

Comment: Can you please post the rest of your code?

Comment: You'd probably be best to encapsulate this in a matrix class that uses a 1D array if you're doing something with the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your code by any chance similar to:

```
int n, m;
matriz cartas;
cin>>n>>m;
cartas(n,rows(m, cards(0)));
```

?

That won't work, `matriz cartas;` is already an initialization. Either define `cartaz` after the `cin` statement, or assign afterwards.

Optimal:

```
int n, m;
cin>>n>>m;
matriz cartas(n,rows(m, cards(0)));
```

Alternative:

```
int n, m;
matriz cartas;
cin>>n>>m;
cartas = matriz(n,rows(m, cards(0)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set an array of size n*m vector[].
you can get each row as index % n and column as index % m.
Much simpler and cleaner.